# Assign hotkeys to paste predefined text

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcut-keys

I am looking for a program that runs on `Ubuntu 12.04+ x86_64` which allows pasting pre-defined text based on hotkey combinations. For instance:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: pastes my username

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: pastes my email

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pastes into which program?

Comment: web browser, note pad, terminal, wine....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `autokey`.

Follow the instructions below:

- **Installation**

  Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

- **Adding Phrases**

  - Open `autokey` using the dash.
  - In the window, expand *My Phrases*.

    `autokey` already comes with four phrases as you can see in the screenshot below.

  [image: autokey default window]

  - You can either modify the existing phrases or make a new phrase using *New* button.
- **Configuring Shortcut Keys**

  - Click on a any phrase name to see the current configuration. In the screenshot above, *First phrase* is selected.
  - To change the shortcut key or *Hotkey*, click on `Set` besides the *Hotkey* and then click on *Press to set* in the new dialog box that appears.

  [image: autokey set hotkey]

  Then press the key combination you wish and select *OK*.
- **Configuring Window Filter**

  - If you wish to use the hotkey only for a particular window, you can set *Window Filter* by selecting *Set* > *Detect Window Properties* and then clicking on the window.
  - Or if you would like the hotkey to work in all the windows, *Clear* the *Window Filter*.
  - *Save* the current phrase and *Run the current script* by clicking on the play-like button on the top write of the window.

  [image: autokey window]
- **Using the new shortcuts**

  - You can close the `autokey` window and use the *Hotkey* to paste the corresponding phrase.

***Further Information:*** *[Autokey Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/w/list)*

Comment: Autokey seems not to be working in 16.04 LTS, sadly.

Comment: Doesn't work when the text is in non-latin language

Comment: It works on 18.04 LTS. [Link](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

Comment: Not working in 19.10, either. I can get the prompt before pasting to come up, but nothing ever pastes.

Comment: Whether it works does not depend on anyones Ubuntu version but whether you are using x11 (works) or wayland ([unsupported](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/87)). Check `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to know which you are currently using.

Answer (score 18):

Since Autokey is defunct, here is how I accomplished this.
First install `xclip` and `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xdotool
```

Now write the text you want to paste and save it in a text file. In this example I wrote my address in a file I called `address`.

Now write the bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xclip -in -selection c ~/scripts/xclip-scripts/address
sleep 0.5 
xdotool key ctrl+v
```

`xclip -in -selection c` tells `xclip` to copy the contents of the file you saved.  In this example, that file is at `~/scripts/xclip-scripts/address`.

The `sleep` command simply allows enough time for `xclip` to finish copying before `xdotool` starts trying to paste the text.

The `xdotool` command actually does the pasting of the text that xclip copied from your text file.

Save your script and make it executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script/<script_name>
```

The last step is to bind a shortcut key to your script.  In Ubuntu this can be set by going to System Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts and create a custom shortcut.

[image: scrot]

Comment: Note that for the shortcut you have to click on the string "Deactivated", the line is not enough since that only opens the dialog "Custom Shortcut".

Comment: `xdotool type --clearmodifiers 'email@example.com'`