# ubuntu how to assign key to email address

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to assign a key combination to enter my email address I get tired of having to type it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the software you are looking for is [autokey](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/autokey), see also this post: [Assign hotkeys to paste predefined text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280604/assign-hotkeys-to-paste-predefined-text) You can install it via

- `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`

if you are using GNOME/Xfce/LXDE or via

- `sudo apt-get install autokey-qt`

if you are using Unity/KDE.