# How do I type a 'µ' (micro) symbol?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

On a German keyboard layout I just need to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to get a 'µ' (micro) symbol.

How to do so on a English (US) keyboard?

Comment: Do you use it (µ) in any special program like Tex?

Comment: The Unicode is "U+03BC". So pressing Ctrl+Shift+U all together, then releasing all keys and typing `03bc` should get you `μ` in gtk applications. If you have a `Compose` key set up on your English (US) keyboard, pressing and releasing the `Compose` key and then typing `m` followed by `u` should do it.

Comment: I don't use `texstudio` but that's a qt-based application and so the Ctrl+Shift+U route won't work. You'll need to use the Compose key route.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 with US layout, AltGR+m+u works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098090/how-do-i-type-a-%C2%B5-micro-symbol#comment1809013_1098090) suggested by @DK Bose within the comments is completely correct, another possible solution is to create custom keyboard shortcut that uses `xdotool` as command in the following way:

```
xdotool type --clearmodifiers 'µ'
```

[image]

Source of the idea is provided within the comments of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/653393/566421). `xdotool` should be installed:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

This shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as it is defined above) works also within `wine` applications, the only specific thing is that you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for about 1 second and then press <kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

When typing in libre office:
From the menu bar select insert, special character
This displays lots of different characters including the one asked for in the question.