# Make US International keyboard not put accents in all characters

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 19.04 and I'm using the English US International keyboard layout because I want to use accented letters like `á`, `ö`, `ã`, etc. Everything works well, but maybe a little too well.

When I type `'` + `a`, I get the character `á`, which is the expected behaviour. But when I type `'` + `s` or `'` + `m` then I get `ś` and `ḿ` respectively and I don't want these characters.

If I type `'` + `s` then I expect the layout to output `'s` instead of `ś`, or if I type `'` + `m` then I expect the layout to output `'m` instead of `ḿ`.

Before somebody says that I'm asking for something crazy because I want the keyboard layout to selectively put accents in some letters, but ignores the accent on other letters, I also use US International keyboard layout on macOS and on Windows computers and they both behave in the way that I expect: `'` + `a` outputs `á` but `'` + `s` outputs `'s` instead of `ś`.

Is it possible to have the same behaviour on Linux?

Comment: I haven't tried, but this may help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Comment: Is it possible to create custom shortcuts for the characters that you need: https://askubuntu.com/a/1098122/566421

Comment: I have noticed that Ubuntu 22.04 partially implements what you want, although with a seemingly random choice of which letters are accentuated and which ones are not.  For example, `'`+`t` gives you `'t`.  All of the letters usually accentuated in most Latin languages get their accents alright, but some other ones do too, such as `ŕ`.  It would be great to have access to the system table determining this behavior but so far I have no idea where does it lie.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way on Linux to achieve the exact behavior you describe. At least it cannot be done only via XKB.

I would suggest that you try another keyboard layout. Assuming that you only need to type accented characters occasionally, check out the *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)* keyboard layout. It only triggers the dead key behavior together with the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> modifier.

<kbd>'</kbd> followed by a => 'a

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> followed by a => á