# How to use keybinding to a string of text?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

What's the Ubuntu 18.04 command to bind a key (CTRL+1 for example) to a text string "my awesome text", to paste "my awesome text" in a text box?

Also, how can I bind ALT+0128 for a EUR sign and ALT+0163 for a POUND sign? I have just transferred from Windows and am used a lot to those alt commands for currency signs. :)

Comment: I edited the comment, what's the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign hotkeys to paste predefined text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280604/assign-hotkeys-to-paste-predefined-text)

Comment: https://github.com/autokey/autokey